# Проверка вводимых данных в скрипте PHP/

Tags: javascript, php, html

Подскажите, проверки на фронте недостаточно? Всегда нужно данные перепроверять на бэке?
Есть анкета на 50 полей, для регистрации юзера, как обычно такое делается?

Comment: Дубликат, уже ответили: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/777019/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD

Answer (score 0):

Нет, конечно, недостаточно. Клиентским проверкам доверять нельзя - их все можно отключить, причём специально и со злым умыслом (меню браузера - Дополнительные инструменты - Инструменты разработчика, как пример).

Проверка на фронте - это скорее для userfriendly-интерфейса, чтобы пользователь уже на этапе ввода увидел, что он что-то ввёл не так и сразу исправил. Например, забыл указать символ @ в электронной почте.

Второстепенный плюс от этого - на сервер не будет отправляться большинство заведомо ошибочных данных и сервер не будет тратить ресурсы на проверку многих неверных значений.